# Can't upload .exe / .msg files, can everything else

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running the following environment:

- PHP 7.1.7
- IIS 10
- Windows 10 1703
- Laravel 5.4.30

Here's my upload script (really simple, accepts all uploads):

```
public function uploadToTemporary(AttachmentUploadRequest $request)
{
    /** @var \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile $file */
    $file = $request->file('file');

    return [
        'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
        'location' => $file->store('temporary'),
    ];
}
```

My `AttachmentUploadRequest` rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'file' => 'file|max:20000',
    ];
}
```

When I upload files with the extensions `.msg`, `.exe`, I receive:

> (1/1) ErrorException
>   fopen(C:\Users\Steve\Websites\tickets\storage\app\temporary/V4WslICBUK3TjK9Cn46nmKkXxtJVAGfDkxJiN9Lg.):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

The thing is, I can upload every other type of file successfully. Here's the file extensions that upload successfully without any permission issues:

- .docx, .doc
- .pptx, .ppt
- .xlsx, .xls
- .txt
- .mp4, .avi, .mp3
- .pdf
- .vrd
- .jpg, .gif, .bmp

Does anyone know why this would happen?

EDIT: I verified that the files are being saved successfully in the temporary windows location by downloading a `1.1mb` executable and uploading it:

[image]

Comment: Are you running mod_security by any chance? If so - check `SecRule` directive

Comment: I'm not aware of a `mod_security` extension. By googling, looks like an Apache module? I don't have it configured, that's for sure.

Comment: The server maybe running DLP.  What about changing the extension from say an .exe to ,rename?  If you rename to a different extension, the web server should accept your exe file.

Comment: Yup, it's a module to Apache that scans the files and prevents them from being uploaded in the first place resulting in 500 error. It also works on a signature basis, so changing extension doesn't work, but seeing that the file is being placed on the server that's not it (and the issue is within PHP). Can you by any chance do what @Leptonator suggested?

Comment: @Leptonator, unfortunately I receive the same exception by renaming the `.exe` to `.rename` or any other. So bizarre!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some antivirus protection is blocking the action. Try disabling it temporarily.

Comment: Only have Windows Defender running, no exceptions, no firewall tinkering at all. I disabled it completely and still receive the same exception unfortunately.

Comment: Did you check the eventlog for more details?

Comment: Nothing in the event log or PHP error log unfortunately.